# git, how to fix integration of submodule

Tags: git

I was monitoring my code using git.
I added a sub directory `angular-seed` by cloning a github repo.

So git now believes this directory.
But I would like to integrate this directory to the rest of the staged files.

I did:

```
$ git add --force angular-seed
```

but `$ git ls-files --stage` doesn't list the content of `angular-seed`.

And

```
$ git-ftp push --user userid --passwd password ftp.cluster014.ovh.net/www/
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'angular-seed'
No changed files for ftp.cluster014.ovh.net/www/. Everything up-to-date.
```

How can I add the directory `angular-seed` to my git repo ?

Comment: Why don't you use git-submodules? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: no I wan to integrate this new directory to the whole project, without using submodules

Comment: You could use Subtree Merging: https://git-scm.com/book/de/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you should not publish your userid and password in question.

(sorry, i can't comment question for lack of reputation)